# Point belong to Sprite in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, sprite, point

How can I know if a point is contained inside of an Sprite in Flex?

For example:

```
// My example point 
var A:Point = new Point(5,5);

// My example sprite
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1);
s.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
s.graphics.lineTo(100,100);
```

The point `A` belong to sprite `s` because its position is inside of it. Is there any function to know it?

I want to do it for all kind of sprites, so use math formulas to calculate linear or quadratic equations (line, circle, rectangle, etc) is not valid for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`hitTestPoint(x, y)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29) on `Sprite`

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I need to use `localToGlobal` before (because it's inside of an event handler) but works like a charm.